# Same tab content is being displaying twice

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I have implemented a simple tabs code. I am trying to move the tabs container inside my li tag, since its a new requirement. After changing the code the same tab content is being displaying twice.

```
  _renderTitles: function () {
    function labels(child, index) {
        var activeClass = (this.state.selected === index ? 'active' : '');

        return (
        <li role="presentation" key={index} className={child.props.liClass}>
            <a href="#" 
            className={`sports-tab-header ${activeClass}`}
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, index)}>
            <h2>{child.props.label}</h2>
            <p className="sports-subtitle">{child.props.subtitle}</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      );
    }
    return (
        <ul className="tabs__labels">
        {this.props.children.map(labels.bind(this))}
      </ul>
    );
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is being shown in both places because of this line:

```
<div className="tabs__content">
  {this.props.children[this.state.selected]}
</div>
```

The `props.children` property holds both children, so you choose to show only the selected content. This is right, except that you're doing this for *each* child due to the `map`:

```
<ul className="tabs__labels">
  {this.props.children.map(labels.bind(this))}
</ul>
```

The solution that works best is to use the same check you had for `this.state.selected === index` to your advantage by setting the content *only* if it's the selected content:

```
var isActive = this.state.selected === index;
var activeClass = (isActive ? 'active' : '');
// Only set the content if active 
var content = isActive ? this.props.children[this.state.selected] : null;
...

// Show the content, which will be null if not active tab
<div className="tabs__content">
  {content}
</div>
```

See [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e767txs/33/).

Comment: but it's not  getting aligned properly like this https://jsfiddle.net/9e767txs/9/embedded/#Result         ...do you know the reason

Comment: That's a structure / CSS issue. You're basically replacing the old content with the new content, and since the old content isn't there anymore, it naturally flows up to the top. If you want the content to align vertically with the content, the new structure with the content within the tab works a little better.

Comment: I have one more doubt can you help me